# spring aop with mybatis dao annotation

Tags: spring, dynamic, datasource, aop, mybatis

I have used `MapperScannerConfigurer` to create mybatis dao, 
but I can't use `Annotation` with the mybatis dao.

Is the order of the wrong？
Spring in the bean and mybatis dao is not in a resource library？

Normal injection is possible, but can not get class annotations

Here are some configuration

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="annotationClass" value="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.wecash"/>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="masterSqlSessionFactory"/>
</bean>



@Aspect
@Component
public class DataSourceAspect {

    public DataSourceAspect(){
        System.out.println("init  DataSourceAspect ");
    }

    private final static LoggerWithMDC LOGGER = LoggerWithMDC.getLogger(DataSourceAspect.class,"dataSource");

    @Around("@annotation(dataSource)")
    public Object processed(ProceedingJoinPoint point, DataSource dataSource) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        return   point.proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly do you want to do with aspect? Do you want to wrap mapper methods with aspect?